# Permission denied but I have permission access

Tags: android, permission-denied

I already put a permission access on my manifest still not saving. I tried this yesterday and its saving my image and now I cant. I dont know what is the problem here. logcat says java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

below is the code

```
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        RelativeLayout content = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.dashBoard);
        content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ imagename+ ".png");

        try {
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();

            }
            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, ostream);
            ostream.close();
            content.invalidate();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        }
    }
});
```

here is the full logcat
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dlb6p5i1nd1kxua/Logcat.txt?dl=0

Comment: check your targetSdkversion should be less than 23

Comment: if greater than 23  accept run time permission from user

Comment: what should i use?

Comment: yes, but if your targetSdkVesrion is greater than 22 you need to access permission run time even if you have permission in manifest

Comment: check thread for more info https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/

Comment: im working with api22. and in the codes `file.createNewFile();` is ignored. is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need use real time permission after SDK API 23 required.

You can ask permission like this code.

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                    if (checkWritePermission()) {
                      // your code
                    } else {
                        requestStoragePermission();
                    }
                } else {
                     // your code
                }
```

You need to check permission and request put this method.

```
  private boolean checkWritePermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }





 private void requestStoragePermission() {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "EXTERNAL STORAGE permission allows us to save image/video. Please allow this permission in App Settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
```

Use `onRequestPermissionsResult` method for handle permission result

Don't forget to put permission on manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I am using API 22 do i really need this?

Comment: I used your answer. still not working and same logcat

Comment: where you run app means real device OR emulator.

Comment: if device 23 up then required real time permission and you need to move on sdk23.